# Java Swing Перекрытие элемента

Tags: java, swing

Доброго времени суток. Как работает позиционирование элементов в Swing относительно слоев?
Как сделать так,чтобы один элемент перекрыл другой? Существует ли какая-то функция?

Comment: Вы под слоями имеете в виду pane? Glass Pane, Root Pane, etc?

Comment: Неправильно сформулировал вопрос. 
Я имею ввиду,что все элементы будут размещены на одной панели JPanel,и,при размещении,например,одной кнопки,мне нужно чтобы она перекрывала другую кнопку. Вторая кнопка будет больше первой по размеру,и,при наведении,мне нужно чтобы вторая кнопка не выглядывала из-за первой (особенности работы Swing),а оставалась все так же под первой.

Comment: а зачем вам такое нужно? какую задачу вы решаете?

Comment: Пишу игру,и создаю в ней главное меню. Там,по середине,есть панель,которая скрыта,и по нажатию на кнопку "Выход" показывается (проверка выхода,так сказать). Суть в том,что на главной панели есть еще кнопки по середине,и,при появлении проверки выхода,они перекрывают её,если на них навести.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать JLayeredPane. Эта панель позволяет добавить слои на любую панель. Вот запускаемый пример.

```
public class LayeredPaneDemo extends JPanel {
    private LayeredPaneDemo() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
        layeredPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 310));
        Point origin = new Point(10, 20);
        String[] layerStrings = {"Red", "Green", "Blue"};
        Color[] layerColors = {Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue};
        for (int i = 0; i < layerStrings.length; i++) {
            JLabel label = createColoredLabel(layerStrings[i], layerColors[i], origin);
            layeredPane.add(label, new Integer(i));
            origin.x += 35;
            origin.y += 35;
        }
        add(layeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private JLabel createColoredLabel(String text, Color color, Point origin) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(color);
        label.setForeground(Color.black);
        label.setBounds(origin.x, origin.y, 140, 140);
        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("LayeredPaneDemo");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            JComponent newContentPane = new LayeredPaneDemo();
            newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
            frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Это сокращенный вариант [LayeredPaneDemo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/LayeredPaneDemoProject/src/components/LayeredPaneDemo.java). Подробная документация [The Layered Pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html#layeredpane).